# How do I pass a complex number from the command-line to sub MAIN?

Tags: raku

I've got the following trivial script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl6

use v6.c;

sub MAIN($x)
{
    say "$x squared is { $x*$x }";
}
```

This works perfectly fine when calling it with real numbers, but I'd like to pass it complex numbers as well.
When I try this as-is, the following happens:

```
% ./square i
Cannot convert string to number: base-10 number must begin with valid digits or '.' in '⏏i' (indicated by ⏏)
  in sub MAIN at ./square line 7
  in block <unit> at ./square line 5

Actually thrown at:
  in sub MAIN at ./square line 7
  in block <unit> at ./square line 5
```

When I change my script to

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl6

use v6.c;

sub MAIN(Complex $x)
{
    say "$x squared is { $x*$x }";
}
```

it stops working completely:

```
% ./square i
Usage:
  square <x>

% ./square 1
Usage:
  square <x>
```

Is there any way to do this in current Perl 6?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works a lot better if you use a [Coercive type declaration](http://design.perl6.org/S02.html#Coercive_type_declarations) from Str to Complex:

```
sub MAIN(Complex(Str) $x)
{
    say "$x squared is { $x*$x }";
}
```

Then:

```
% ./squared.pl 1
1+0i squared is 1+0i
% ./squared.pl 1+2i
1+2i squared is -3+4i
```

Comment: Thanks, that works nicely.  It's a bit unfortunate that `./square i` won't work (Method 'Complex' not found for invocant of class 'Str'), you have to do `./square 0+1i`, but I can live with that.

Answer (score 6):

Actually what you wrote works perfectly

```sh
$ ./test.pl6 2+3i
2+3i squared is -5+12i
```

---

The problem only shows up because you don't actually give it a [Complex](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Complex) number on the command line.

```sh
$ ./test.pl6 2
Usage:
  ./test.p6 <x>
```

---

What you really want is to coerce other [Numeric](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Numeric) types to [Complex](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Complex). So you should write something like the following.

```perl6
#!/usr/bin/env perl6

use v6.c;

sub MAIN ( Complex(Real) $x ) {
    say "$x squared is { $x*$x }";
}
```

I used [Real](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Real) instead of [Numeric](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Numeric), because [Complex](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Complex) already has the rest of that covered.